# What else I must do allow my method to handle any type of objects

Tags: java, generics, object, linked-list

So to allow any type object I must use generics in my code.

I have rewrote this method to do so, but then when I create an object, for example Milk, it won't let me pass it to my method.

Ether there's something wrong with my generic revision, or Milk object I created is not good.

How should I pass my object correctly and add it to linked list?

This is a method that causes error when I insert an item:

```
   public void insertFirst(T dd)  // insert at front of list
   {
      Link newLink = new Link(dd);   // make new link

      if( isEmpty() )                // if empty list,
         last = newLink;             // newLink <-- last
      else
         first.previous = newLink;   // newLink <-- old first
      newLink.next = first;          // newLink --> old first
      first = newLink;               // first --> newLink
   }
```

This is my class I try to insert into linked list:

```
class Milk
{
    String brand;
    double size;
    double price;

    Milk(String a, double b, double c)
    {
        brand = a;
        size = b;
        price = c;
    }
}
```

This is test method to insert the data:

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {                             // make a new list
      DoublyLinkedList theList = new DoublyLinkedList();

      // this causes:
      // The method insertFirst(Comparable) in the type DoublyLinkedList is not applicable for the arguments (Milk)
      theList.insertFirst(new Milk("brand", 1, 2));      // insert at front

      theList.displayForward();     // display list forward
      theList.displayBackward();    // display list backward
      }  // end main()
   }  // end class DoublyLinkedApp
```

Declarations:

```
class Link<T extends Comparable<T>>
   {}

class DoublyLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>>
   {}
```

Comment: What is `Link` and `DoublyLinkedList` classes? Are you sure they are not `Link<T>` `and DoublyLinkedList<T>`? Please add at least the declarations for these classes. Also - what is your error EXACTLY?

Comment: You are right. I will add declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your error you have defined `T` to be Comparable like

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

but you are adding a type which is not Comparable.  Its not clear why your class needs to be comparable as you don't appear to using this in your insert method so I would drop the requirement.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> {
```

If you are going to copy what a class in the JDK does, I suggest you understand how it works by reading its source.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html

Comment: Note that there is also the usage of *raw types* issue.

Comment: But a cause for an error nontheless, assuming `first` is of type `Link<T>` (as it should be), since you try to assign a raw type into it.

Answer (score 1):

You must instantiate you list  like this:

```
DoublyLinkedList<Milk> theList = new DoublyLinkedList<Milk>();
```

And i almost forgot...

```
Milk implements Comparable<Milk>
```

Comment: This causes: Bound mismatch: The type Milk is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>> of the type DoublyLinkedList<T>`. But fixes my previous error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `Milk` isn't good enough - but that is not all.

It should be :

```
class Milk implements Comparable<Milk>
```

(you need to implement this interface).

In addition:

```
Link newLink = new Link(dd);
```

and

```
DoublyLinkedList theList = new DoublyLinkedList();
```

are of type `DoublyLinkedList<Object>` (They are *raw types*) - (and same for `Link<Object>`) which are not comparable of the desired type as well (`Object` is not `Comparable<Object>`)

So you should do in order to fix it:

1. Make sure `Milk` implements `Comparable<Milk>`
2. Declare your variables and initialize them as the generic type: `DoublyLinkedList<Milk>` and `Link<T>`

An alternative (For 1) - if you don't need the `Comparable` functionality - just declare them both as:

```
class DoublyLinkedList<T>
class Link<T>
```